# Volley request is not receiving

Tags: android, android-volley

In my Project if I add parameters with url and then make a request that is being received by the server. But if I use GET params method then the request is not being received by the server.

Successful request

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final EditText name1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        final EditText price1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        final EditText description1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);

        Button submit=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);


        submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            protected Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
                return super.clone();
            }

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                final String name=name1.getText().toString();
                final double price= Double.parseDouble(price1.getText().toString());
                final String description=description1.getText().toString();
                RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
                String url ="http://192.168.0.101/webservice/create_product.php?name=symphony&price=1000&description=from_android";
                StringRequest sr=new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jo=new JSONObject(response);
                            Log.d("From Volley",+jo.getInt("success")+"   "+jo.getString("message"));
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }


                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.e("From Volley", error.getMessage());

                    }
                });
                Log.d("From Volley",sr.getUrl()+"   "+sr.toString());

                queue.add(sr);

            }
        });

    }
}
```

Failed request

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final EditText name1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        final EditText price1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        final EditText description1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);

        Button submit=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);


        submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            protected Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
                return super.clone();
            }

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                final String name=name1.getText().toString();
                final double price= Double.parseDouble(price1.getText().toString());
                final String description=description1.getText().toString();
                RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
                String url ="http://192.168.0.101/webservice/create_product.php";
                StringRequest sr=new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jo=new JSONObject(response);
                            Log.d("From Volley",+jo.getInt("success")+"   "+jo.getString("message"));
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }


                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.e("From Volley", error.getMessage());

                    }
                }){
                    @Override
                    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                        Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        params.put("name",name);
                        params.put("price", String.valueOf(price));
                        params.put("description",description);
                        return  params;

                    }

                };

                Log.d("From Volley",sr.getUrl()+"   "+sr.toString());

                queue.add(sr);

            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: For that you need to accept request as POST method and you need to change your request method as method.POST

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you use GET method that you have to build URL before make request, `getParams()` is used when request method is post...

Build URL for GET As follow

```
 Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder();
 builder.scheme("http")
 .authority("192.168.0.101")
 .appendPath("webservice")
 .appendPath("create_product.php")
 .appendQueryParameter("name", name)
 .appendQueryParameter("price",  String.valueOf(price))
 .appendQueryParameter("description", description);

 String url = builder.build().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 StringRequest sr=new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
 }
```

change to

```
 StringRequest sr=new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
 }
```